navigator.serviceWorker.ready does not resolve
(Note: other issues here, and here, are not the same as this)
Hi folks,
I don't seem to be able to get the ready property of the ServiceWorkerContainer to resolve:
const serviceWorkerScriptPath = new URL('./worker.js', import.meta.url);

const registration = await navigator.serviceWorker.register(serviceWorkerScriptPath, {
    scope: serviceWorkerScriptPath.pathname,
});

if(registration.active) {
  console.log("Service worker active"); // <== This is logged
}

console.log(`Waiting for service worker ready...`);

const readyReg = await navigator.serviceWorker.ready; // <== Never resolves

console.log(`Service worker ready`); // <== Never logged

(my worker.js is not in the root path, so I'm just using the URL to avoid hard coding the path)
Documentation seems to imply that this ready promise should resolve when "the current page has an active worker"
Is there some reason this ready promise would not resolve in this case? I've found this whole API to be pretty confusing, and I don't even know if I need this promise to resolve, but I'm ultimately trying to use the periodicSync API, and all the examples there seem to want this ready promise to be resolved.

Remove the "scope" option, the scope should be the path for the current page, not where the worker.js is located.

I have tried all kinds of values for scope, including no value. Doesn't seem to help. Still hangs

OK.. so I think I made progress. My worker script is in a sub-folder below the root. For reasons I don't understand (other than.. "security"?), you can't actually use a JS file in any place other than root. I'm not sure if that's actually true, but if it is it really should be documented as such. If I move the "worker.js" to the root folder, it loads and the ready promise resolves. I guess that ready promise is looking for workers in the "/" scope, and if the script is in a subfolder it's not loading in this scope. I am not a fan of this api :/
